# Is it a good practice to store the main's args to a global variable?

Tags: java

I am making a java program and I am using the input `args` a lot. I don't want the main function to be very big, so I was wandering if it is a good practice to store the arguments to a global `static String` variable, so that I could use them in functions.

Comment: I do it all the time, I don't see a reason not to. It can really simplify code if they dont change and you dot want to constantly pass them I would think.

Comment: I'd be inclined to process them in `main`, and store the results in a global instance of a `class` that models the arguments. Then you can do all the command line argument checking in one place. (I use `gnu.getopt`).

Comment: You could also use property files instead of the `args` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bad design to provide global access to the command line arguments for the simple reason that in a good design, only one part of your code needs to process the command line arguments: the part that parses them to translate them from their input representation (a sequence of strings) into meaningful control information for your program (boolean flags, lists of Path objects, etc).